# Share cookies to subdomain on localhost

Tags: php, cookies

I create a bunch of cookies for authentication purposes and a part of the website allows the users to navigate to the UK part of the site. This is enabled by having a uk prefix in the domain. (e.g uk.domain.com).

I basically have a small script that checks to see if the subdomain is called UK then I deliver the UK content.

How can I make it so all the cookies on domain.com transfer to uk.domain.com?

I've tried ...

... setting the cookie to the just root domain

```
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/", "localhost")
```

... adding a dot to the beginning of the domain

```
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/", ".localhost")
```

... creating the cookie on both domains

```
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/", "localhost")
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/", "uk.localhost")
```

... creating cookies without any domain or path.

```
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/")
 setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123)
```

I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found out that you cannot set localhost as a cookie on chrome. It needs to be a registry controlled domain and not an IP or intranet hostname.

I found a workaround by basically turning localhost into a domain.

I added this to the host file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) -

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.com    
127.0.0.1    uk.localhost.com
```

then created the cookies with the localhost domain

```
setcookie("auth", "blahblah", time() + 123, "/", "localhost.com")
```

This allowed me to access the auth cookie from http://uk.localhost.com (or pretty much any subdomain).

Comment: In macos, hosts file is located under `/private/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 4):

I want to expand the answer of [@slothinspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6136537/slothinspace): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38669116/10712525

*I can't put this as a comment because it too long.*

---

I spent hours looking for this solution.

In short, you can't set the domain in a cookie for `.localhost` and expect it to work correctly (expecting it to work for a subdomain and the main domain). You can also experiment some problems if you try to do it more explicitly, eg: `subdomain.localhost`.

Just to clarify: the **Domain** attribute allows the cookies to be shared between the main domain and subdomains.

If you set the localhost URL in `/etc/hosts` like in the selected answer, you can put `.localhost.com` or `subdomain.localhost.com` as the cookie domain and it will work fine.

I have tested it in Chrome, Brave and Firefox.

---

Final request: Don't forget to upvote this question and the correct answer, to make it easier to find.

And another thing, thanks for reading this and I apologize for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I found a trick that doesn't need editing the 'hosts' file and will let you keep using localhost.

In my case, I needed to set a cookie on localhost and let service.localhost see that cookie. When inspecting the cookie on localhost, the domain property didn't have a leading dot. When I tried setting a leading dot manually, even localhost couldn't see it.

So my fix was to move everything one subdomain level down.
localhost became apps.localhost and service.localhost became service.apps.localhost